# Salesforce Before Insert or Upsert list must not have two identically equal elements error in my debug

Tags: apex

I have this awesome code running in my org. I would like to create a case to the accounts in the query I run and want to add a case to track. But I am getting the 
System.ListException: Before Insert or Upsert list must not have two identically equal elements error and I could not create a case

Below is my code. Please help me understand where I am I missing to write the insert statement.

```
public class PD_WelcomeMaroPost {

    @future(callout=true)
    public static void sendEmailThroughMaro(string myInpEmail) {
        string successContacts = '';
        string failureContacts = '';

        List<Stripe_Subscripton__c> subsToUpdate = new List<Stripe_Subscripton__c>();
        List<Case> newCase = new List<Case>();
        Case cs = new Case();

        // SQL to fetch FBO who Joined Today
        list<Account> conts = new list<Account> ([SELECT Id, name, Email_FLP_com__c,
        (SELECT Id
        FROM Stripe_Subscriptons__r
        WHERE Start_Date__c= TODAY
            AND Status__c='active'
            AND Welcome_Email__C = false
        LIMIT 1)
    from account
    where ID IN (
        select Distributor__c
        from Stripe_Subscripton__c
        where Start_Date__c= TODAY
            AND Status__c='active'
            AND Welcome_Email__C = false)
    AND  Email_FLP_com__c != NULL
    LIMIT 100]);

        system.debug('>>>>>>>>>>' + conts);
        overallEmail myEmail = new overallEmail();

        for(Account c : conts){

            myEmail.email.campaign_id = 172;
            myEmail.email.bcc = 'shrikant.bhise@nextsphere.com';
            myEmail.email.contact.Email = c.Email_FLP_com__c;
            myEmail.email.contact.first_name = c.name;

            /**MAp<String, String> tags = new Map<String, String>();
            tags.put('firstName', c.name);
            myEmail.email.tags = tags;**/
            system.debug('#### Input JSON: ' + JSON.serialize(myEmail));


            try{
                String endpoint = 'http://api.maropost.com/accounts/1173/emails/deliver.json?auth_token=j-V4sx8ueUT7eKM8us_Cz5JqXBzoRrNS3p1lEZyPUPGcwWNoVNZpKQ';
                HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
                req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
                req.setMethod('POST');
                req.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
                req.setbody(JSON.serialize(myEmail));
                Http http = new Http();
                system.debug('Sending email');
                HTTPResponse response = http.send(req); 
                system.debug('sent email');
                string resultBodyGet = '';
                resultBodyGet = response.getBody();
                system.debug('Output response:' + resultBodyGet);
                maroResponse myMaroResponse = new maroResponse();
                myMaroResponse = (maroResponse) JSON.deserialize(resultBodyGet, maroResponse.class);
                system.debug('#### myMaroResponse: ' + myMaroResponse);
                if(myMaroResponse.message == 'Email was sent successfully')
                   successContacts = successContacts + ';' + c.Email_FLP_com__c;
                else
                    failureContacts = failureContacts + ';' + c.Email_FLP_com__c;
            }
            catch (exception e) {
                failureContacts = failureContacts + ';' + c.Email_FLP_com__c;
                system.debug('#### Exception caught: ' + e.getMessage());                
            }

            c.Stripe_Subscriptons__r[0].Welcome_Email__c = true;
            c.Stripe_Subscriptons__r[0].Welcome_Email_Sent_Date__c = system.today();
            subsToUpdate.add(c.Stripe_Subscriptons__r[0]);


               cs.RecordTypeId = '012d0000000hIcH';
               cs.Status = 'Welcome Email Sent';
               cs.AccountId = c.Id;
               cs.OwnerId = '005d000000363QwAAI';
               cs.Subject = 'FLP360 New User';
               cs.Description = 'Email Sent Succesfully';
               cs.origin = 'Email';          
               newCase.add(cs);


        }

        Update subsToUpdate;
        insert newCase;
        system.debug('newCase');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're currently declaring the Case outside of the for-loop over Accounts:

```
Case cs = new Case();
...
for(Account c : conts){
    ...
    cs.RecordTypeId = '012d0000000hIcH';
    cs.Status = 'Welcome Email Sent';
    cs.AccountId = c.Id;
    cs.OwnerId = '005d000000363QwAAI';
    cs.Subject = 'FLP360 New User';
    cs.Description = 'Email Sent Succesfully';
    cs.origin = 'Email';
    newCase.add(cs);
}
```

So, each iteration is updating the same instance of Case, and adding it to the `newCase` list each time.

You need to move the Case declaration inside the for loop, so that each `cs` is different:

```
for(Account c : conts){
    Case cs = new Case();
    ...
    cs.RecordTypeId = '012d0000000hIcH';
    cs.Status = 'Welcome Email Sent';
    cs.AccountId = c.Id;
    cs.OwnerId = '005d000000363QwAAI';
    cs.Subject = 'FLP360 New User';
    cs.Description = 'Email Sent Succesfully';
    cs.origin = 'Email';
    newCase.add(cs);
}
```